# PHP COOKIE visits counter increases by 2

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I want to store a cookie, using PHP, containing the number of pageviews for a user.
This is my code:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['visits'])) $_COOKIE['visits'] = 0;
    $visited = $_COOKIE['visits'] + 1;
    setcookie('visits', $visited, time() + $h * 3600, "/");
```

For some reason, the counter increases by 2 instead of 1. Where is the bug?

Comment: how many times that code block called?

Comment: just once, it is in else coundition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Use brackets! They are there for a good reason, then your if would expand to:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['visits'])){
  $visited = 0;
}else{
  $visited = $_COOKIE['visits'] + 1;
}

setcookie('visits', $visited, time() + $h * 3600, "/");
```

Notice, that I have exchanged `$_COOKIE['vistits']` with `$visited`. In the next call, `$_COOKIE` will be filled, there is no need to fill it by yourself.

Here could be your problem: When do you read the `$_COOKIE`? Possible to an wrong time...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I fixed it, was a problem with

add_action('init', 'load_function'); in wordpress.